# Mathematical induction find values of skipping numbers.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a question which is finding the value of a skipping numbers mathematical induction problem.

The problem is as follows:
Prove by mathematical induction, that $$1^3+2^3+3^3+\dots+n^3=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}.$$
I can successfully prove this.

The next part asks to find the value of 
$$2^3+4^3+6^3+\dots+30^3$$

I can find the sum of up to thirty but I don't know what to subtract it from. Thank you for your help

Comment: How about set $n=15$ and multiply both sides by $2^3=8$...

Comment: Thank you @TheSimpliFire

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply observe that $$\begin{align}
2^3+4^3+6^3+\cdots+30^3&=(2\times1)^3+(2\times2)^3+(2\times3)^3+\cdots+(2\times15)^3\\
&=2^3\left(1^3+2^3+3^3+\cdots15^3\right)\\
&=2^3\left[\frac{15^2(15+1)^2}{4}\right]\\
&=115200
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you divide the sum by $2^3$? :)